# Show images in a Reactjs page only when a variable has a particular value

Tags: reactjs

I have the following simple code that has a small radio button selection and it shows two images at the bottom of the form. I would like this code to show NO images when it loads and, depending on the selection being made in the radio button choice, just show the single image that represents the selection. Basically a virtual `if this.state.programmingmodel === 'event-driven' then <HoverImage src={longrunning} hoverSrc={longrunninghover} />` (and same thing for `eventdriven`).

I have tried to play with adding an `onSubmitForm` syntax to the `<HoverImage>` section(s) but it didn't really work out. I don't think I need to create another "event" because I want to re-use the `onSubmit` event.

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import "./index.css"

import HoverImage from "react-hover-image";
import longrunning from './longrunning.jpg';
import longrunninghover from './longrunninghover.jpg';
import eventdriven from './eventdriven.jpg';
import eventdrivenhover from './eventdrivenhover.jpg';

class App extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      programmingmodel: "long-running"
    };
  }

  onValChange = (event) => {
    this.setState({
      [event.target.name]: event.target.value,
    });
  };

  onCheckValChange = (e) => {
    this.setState({ [e.target.name]: e.target.checked });
  };

  onSubmitForm = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    console.log("state", this.state);
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <h1>Containers product selection </h1>
        <form onSubmit={this.onSubmitForm}>
          <br/>
          <b> Programming model </b>
          <br/>
          <label>
            <input
              type="radio"
              name="programmingmodel"
              value="long-running"
              checked={this.state.programmingmodel === 'long-running'}
              onChange={this.onValChange}
            />
            <span>Long-running </span>
          </label>
          <label>
            <input
              type="radio"
              name="programmingmodel"
              value="event-driven"
              checked={this.state.programmingmodel === 'event-driven'}
              onChange={this.onValChange}
            />
            <span>Event-driven </span>
          </label>
          <br/>
          <button type="submit">Submit</button>
          <br/>
        </form>
        <br/>
        <HoverImage src={longrunning} hoverSrc={longrunninghover} />
        <br/>
        <HoverImage src={eventdriven} hoverSrc={eventdrivenhover} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 0):

You only have to check for the status of your state and decide which component to render. I've removed the form, and some unused code, as it's not needed.

like this:

```
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      programmingmodel: "long-running"
    };
  }

  onValChange = (event) => {
    this.setState({
      [event.target.name]: event.target.value
    });
  };

  onCheckValChange = (e) => {
    this.setState({ [e.target.name]: e.target.checked });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <h1>Containers product selection </h1>
        <b> Programming model </b>
        <br />
        <label>
          <input
            type="radio"
            name="programmingmodel"
            value="long-running"
            checked={this.state.programmingmodel === "long-running"}
            onChange={this.onValChange}
          />
          <span>Long-running </span>
        </label>
        <label>
          <input
            type="radio"
            name="programmingmodel"
            value="event-driven"
            checked={this.state.programmingmodel === "event-driven"}
            onChange={this.onValChange}
          />
          <span>Event-driven </span>
        </label>
        {this.state.programmingmodel === "long-running" ? (
          <HoverImage src={longrunning} hoverSrc={longrunninghover} />
        ) : (
          <HoverImage src={eventdriven} hoverSrc={eventdrivenhover} />
        )}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Regarding the loading state, I would do it on the parent component and wouldn't mix the logics.

Comment: Thanks @gilamran! If I try to factor your suggestion into my code it works when it loads the page (that is, it loads the right image based on the initial state I set `this.state.programmingmodel` in the constructor). However, when I submit the form, I see that the state changes (in console.log) but it does not trigger the change of the image. I assume the check on the state needs to be done `onSubmit` (also?)?

Comment: Also, preferably, the images should not show up before submitting the form (if possible).

Comment: As I mentioned on the answer, you shouldn't deal with loading on this component. you should probably let the parent "know" about the loading state.